# How do I wrap text around a View in React Native?

Tags: css, react-native, layout

I'd like to create a component which will display a View called *label* on the top-right corner and some text surrounding it, similarly to what you'll get on a web layout when you `float: right` a `<div>` with CSS. Both the label and the text may have varying lengths. I've been trying for a while to make the text from the 2nd row onwards wrap and expand below the label, but with no luck.

This is my code so far:

```js
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', borderWidth: 1}}>
  <Text
    numberOfLines={3}
    style={{flex: 1}}
  >
    lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor
  </Text>
  <View>
    <Text style={{backgroundColor: 'wheat'}}>
      label 1234
    </Text>
  </View>
</View>
```

And the resulting render:
[image: RN rendered component]

This is what I'd like to obtain instead:
[image: WEB rendered component]

Comment: Wrapped text arround a View is not supported out of the box in RN ...

Comment: Can you show an `image` example of the desired output? From anywhere??

Comment: @KartikeyVaish I just added an example made with html/css.

Comment: Please check this  may be it's helpful for you https://snack.expo.io/ZHH7cvdVG

Comment: I'm not sure you can accomplish this because of the `flexDirection: row` style. You may want to try making the label text absolutely position.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple, yet kinda "hacky" way would be to go with `float: right;`, as you already tried. For this to work, the flex styles have to be set to "initial" both on the outer view and text component following the floated view. Also, this works only when the floated element comes first.

```
<View style={{display: 'initial', borderWidth: 1}}>
    <View style={{float: 'right'}}>
        <Text style={{backgroundColor: 'wheat'}}>
            label 1234
        </Text>
    </View>
    <Text
        style={{display: 'initial'}}
        numberOfLines={3}
    >
        lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor ydrgsr serg er
    </Text>
</View>
```

Live example: https://snack.expo.io/iuNiJSaYW

Comment: This only works on RN Web, on Android and iOS there's no float option for styles so it gets ignored.